Convert Google Calendar link to iCalendar
I do not want to use Google anymore, unfortunately, there is one critical service that I use that creates Google Calendar Links to add it.
Then I need to manually add to my Apple’s Calendar.
Is there any way to convert those invites/links?

Why don't you add the google account and sync calendar with the apple device? This way, you can have all the google calendar appointments appearing in your apple devices.

I do not want to use any Google service anymore

What does using this service actually create?  If it's just an .ICS file, import it directly.  If it's sending you a URL, I don't know how that works.

Also... what service?

It can be a weekend project
